# The Navbar is not going in lg and md screens on right top corner

Tags: html, css, button, navbar

I want that right side header nav to be hidden.
[image]

```
<div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <a href="Chicken.html">
        <div id="Chicken-tile">
          <span class="Chicken"></span></div><br class="navbar visible-xs"> Chicken</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="Beef.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon"></span><br class="visible-xs-block"> Beef</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="Sushi.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon"></span><br class="visible-xs-block"> Sushi</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- #nav-list -->
</div>
<!-- .collapse .navbar-collapse -->
<!-- .container -->
```

Comment: can you please share your code or working demo?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the [how to ask a good question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question. We are not here to do the work for you. Please give it a try yourself first while using google. If you run into issues with the code then we are here to help you - if you describe what you've tried and what the actual issue is where you ran into.